# Is it possible to make elements in a Visual Studio .sln file conditional?

Tags: msbuild, sln-file

Is it possible to make elements in a Visual Studio .sln file conditional?

Although the .sln file is oddly not in MSBuild or even XML format, I would love to use a similar syntax.

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "HelloProj", 
    "HelloProj.csproj",
    "{61729087-EEA0-4C80-BF72-4205970239F9}"
EndProject
```

would become:

```
Project( Condition="Some Condition Stuff"
    "{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "HelloProj", ...
```

So, if "Some Condition Stuff" evaluated to false, the project HelloProj would not be included when you open the solution. I doubt this is feasible, I'm not even sure if the solution file has a concept of properties/variable, but I thought I would ask anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing exists that I am aware of that will fully remove a project from being loaded when you open a solution. I don't think that is the intent of the solution file, rather if you need to include/exclude projects based on some criteria at open time it's probably safe to consider using multiple solution files where each solution contains the correct projects for a situation.

However, for C#/C++/C projects you *can* use the Configuration Manager to modify the build and deploy behaviour for each project in your solution based on the Platform and Configuration chosen. In the solution explorer, right-click on your solution and choose 'Configuration Manager...'.

[image: Screen capture of the Configuration Manager in use to turn off building a project in a solution for the Any CPU platform and Debug configuration]